# Editing ObservableCollection's SelectedItem Without Bound Controls Seeing Edits Until They Are Saved

Tags: c#, wcf, data-binding, collections

I have a view containing a `ListView` and an "Edit" Button. The ListView's `ItemSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Account>` property on the underlying view model. Its `SelectedItem` property is also bound to the view model.

When the edit button is clicked, the existing view model launches an editing  view/view model pair ("editing screen") allowing the user to edit the currently selected `Account`. The `Account` to edit is determined by the main view model's `SelectedItem` property.

**Problem:** Any changes made in the editing screen are immediately reflected in the other screen's `ListView`, even before the edit screen's "Save" button is clicked. Why this happens makes sense--`Account` is raising property change events when its properties are changed and the `ListView` is processing those notifications.

**Desired Outcome:** Bound controls (like the `ListView`) should only see editing screen changes  after"Save" is clicked.

### Possible Solutions

- Suspend Account's property change notifications while editing is underway. Disadvantages: If a manual data-binding update is performed while an `Account` instance is being edited, the "in-progress" changes will appear on the `ListView` even though those changes haven't been raising notifications. Also, if the user launches a second edit window for the same `Account`, they will see the "in-progress" changes. Idea rejected.
- Have the editing screen view model wrap the `Account` instance in some kind of `EditingAccount` class that copies changes made to it back to the original `Account` only when `Save()` is called. Should the editing screen take on the responsibility of facilitating this wrapping or should it ask the service layer to do it?

What do you think of these options? How do you solve this problem when you encounter it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with some version of the second option. Basically this is a variation of the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern which is considered the "right" way to do WPF/Silverlight code. Basically you should have a ModelView object for each "screen" (View) that wraps the model and exposes the model in a format specific to the View so it does exactly what the View needs and NO MORE.

Comment: Actually the MVVM in the above answer is a link to a Microsoft article. But if you search for MVVM and C# you should get quite a few.